# How do I rename the splitting variables in a split histogram?

Tags: r, lattice

Specifically I have the following code:

```
histogram(~di01a | sex, type="count" , nint = 20, stripes =c("horizontal") , data = ALLBUSNEU)
```

It generates the following visual.

[image]

The variable sex can have the values 1 and 2 but it displays "sex" for both histograms which is the first problem:
How do get it to display 1 and 2?

Second issue:
I want them to be displayed as "Male" and "Female" is that possible without altering the variable itself?

Comment: Do not you want to put both plots on one diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing in a `factor` with your `sex` column.

This is how your code should look like:

```
library(lattice)

ALLBUSNEU$sex <- as.factor(ALLBUSNEU$sex)
histogram(~di01a | sex, type="count" , nint = 20, stripes =c("horizontal") , data = ALLBUSNEU)
```

> Second issue: I want them to be displayed as "Male" and "Female"?

This is the idiomatic way of doing it in `lattice`, as referred to in its documentation and [other referenced materials](https://www.statmethods.net/RiA/lattice.pdf) as well:

```
ALLBUSNEU$sex <- factor(ALLBUSNEU$sex, labels=c("male", "female"))
histogram(~di01a | sex, type="count" , nint = 20, stripes =c("horizontal") , data = ALLBUSNEU)
```

If your concern was that this will alter the original column, then create an extra variable (column) to leave this column untouched.

```
ALLBUSNEU$sexFactor <- factor(ALLBUSNEU$sex, labels=c("male", "female"))
histogram(~di01a | sexFactor, type="count" , nint = 20, stripes =c("horizontal") , data = ALLBUSNEU)
```

If you also do not want to create a new column on the dataframe, then make a copy of the original dataframe, and do your visualization on the duplicated copy where you can perform proper type conversion.

### Explanation

Since I do not have your data, I am going to use `mtcars` to demonstrate the idea.

The following code:

```
library(lattice)
histogram(~mpg | cyl, type="count" , nint = 20, stripes =c("horizontal") , data = mtcars)
```

Produces:
[image]

This is because `mtcars$cyl` is numeric and isn't recognized as a factor. `lattice` does not know to treat this any differently than it would with a numeric variable.

When I perform a conversion, and call the same code, lattice is now aware that each value in this column is a factor level, and use its string representation:

```
library(lattice)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
histogram(~mpg | cyl, type="count" , nint = 20, stripes =c("horizontal") , data = mtcars)
```

This produces:
[image]